# Simple NN in Keras - Bad classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

In order to get an understanding of Keras with TensorFlow backend for further research projects, I've tried to implement a NN for a simple classification problem. I only want to differentiate [randomly distributed points in 2D into two categories depending on their coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMZPY.png) (colour indicates category).
The associated code to generate the data is:

```python
import numpy as np    
np.random.seed(40)

def createData(N=120, M=75):
    train_x1 = np.random.random(size=N)
    train_x2 = np.random.random(size=N)

    test_x1 = np.random.random(size=M)
    test_x2 = np.random.random(size=M)

    train_x = np.zeros((N, 2))
    train_y = np.zeros((N, 1))

    test_x = np.zeros((M, 2))
    test_y = np.zeros((M, 1))

    for i in range(N):
        train_x[i][0] = train_x1[i]
        train_x[i][1] = train_x2[i]
        if train_x1[i] < 0.5:
            if train_x2[i] < 0.5:
                train_y[i][0] = 1
            else:
                train_y[i][0] = 2
        else:
            if train_x2[i] < 0.5:
                train_y[i][0] = 2
            else:
                train_y[i][0] = 1

    for j in range(M):
        test_x[j][0] = test_x1[j]
        test_x[j][1] = test_x2[j]
        if test_x1[j] < 0.5:
            if test_x2[j] < 0.5:
                test_y[j][0] = 1
            else:
                test_y[j][0] = 2
        else:
            if test_x2[j] < 0.5:
                test_y[j][0] = 2
            else:
                test_y[j][0] = 1

    return train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y
```

My code for neural network is as follows:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y, x, y = createData()

# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500, batch_size=25)

# Evaluation
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# Predictions
predictions = model.predict(x)
rounded = [round(z[0]) for z in predictions]
print(rounded)
```

My problem is, that the neural network reaches an accuracy of 47.5% with the above mentioned seeds and configuration. It assigns [all test coordinates to only one category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNCvF.png). However, other configurations (more layers, more/less neurons, other activation functions, other loss functions, etc.) lead to similar results.

The last lines of the "epoch monitor" on the shell looks like this:

```
Epoch 490/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.3351 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 491/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.1866 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 492/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.3524 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 493/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.2608 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 494/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.3269 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 495/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.2039 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 496/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.1786 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 497/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.2488 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 498/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.3090 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 499/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.3457 - acc: 0.4750     
Epoch 500/500
120/120 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -8.1235 - acc: 0.4750
```

How can I improve the neural network to get away from this dumb behaviour? Thank you very much for any comments and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would check that your input data is created / labeled correctly.  Try printing out a couple values to make sure it makes sense.

Secondly, I usually see this issue when the learning rate is to high.  You can try either removing the hidden layer with 10 neurons in the center or lowering the learning rate.  I think a network that many layers deep is overkill for this problem.  Try using this for your compile line.

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

A learning rate of 0.001 is the default for Adam but I have found that if 0.001 does not converge using 0.0001 always will.

Comment: The additional parameter of learning rate has lead to significant improvements. With the following code I got an at least decent result: 
`model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])`